# There is a way to publish and consume message from Django to react?

Tags: reactjs, django, sockets, django-rest-framework, react-redux

I’m new in Django and I’m trying to “send messages״ from Django to react.

My motivation is to make my react app more dynamic.

I have a dashboard in my react app and I want to render dashboard component once data changed in Django.

Another case:
I have a posts and comments in my app and I want when some one add a comment to post to render comments component to show to all of the users the new comment without refresh the page.

I think maybe I can use some message broker and publish a message from Django and react will consume the message and render components.

There is something like that?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [channels](https://github.com/django/channels), it is a websocket pkg for django.

The other way, is use poll request, but it not a good way.